# Raising and lowering 3D harmonic oscillator state

Tags: quantum-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator

A good solution to the 3D harmonic oscillator is shown [here](http://quantummechanics.ucsd.edu/ph130a/130_notes/node244.html).  This gives the basis states $|n,\ell\rangle$

My question is if there are some operators comparable to the 1D SHO that will raise either n or $\ell$.  For example, if I wanted to find the second order perturbations by an H' that depended on $r^2$, could I apply the same techniques as with the 1D raising operators?